# LifeBar : Cannot hide the lifebar after exiting the scene

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I've added a lifebar to my application, and it works well but once i quit the scene, the object is still visible. I've tried most of codes in tutorial, in vain.

lifeBar is declared in my `function scene:enterScene(event)` like this :

```
lifeBar = {}
lives = 12
maxLives = 12
lifeBar[0] = display.newImage("fuel_bar12.png")
lifeBar[1] = display.newImage("fuel_bar11.png")
lifeBar[2] = display.newImage("fuel_bar10.png")
lifeBar[3] = display.newImage("fuel_bar9.png")
lifeBar[4] = display.newImage("fuel_bar8.png")
lifeBar[5] = display.newImage("fuel_bar7.png")
lifeBar[6] = display.newImage("fuel_bar6.png")
lifeBar[7] = display.newImage("fuel_bar5.png")
lifeBar[8] = display.newImage("fuel_bar4.png")
lifeBar[9] = display.newImage("fuel_bar3.png")
lifeBar[10] = display.newImage("fuel_bar2.png")
lifeBar[11] = display.newImage("fuel_bar1.png")
lifeBar[12] = display.newImage("fuel_bar1.png")

livesValue = display.newText(string.format("%d", lives), 300,30,native.systemFontBold, 16)
livesValue:setTextColor(255,255,255)
screenGroup:insert(livesValue)

for i = 1, maxLives do
    lifeBar[i].anchorX=0
    lifeBar[i].anchorY=0.6
    lifeBar[i].x = fuel_title.x +114+15
    lifeBar[i].y = 37 -- start at 10,10
    lifeBar[i].isVisible=true

end
```

But i don't know how to put "off" this table in my function 
`function scene:exitScene(event)`

I've tried to create a group in the `scene:createScene(event)` :

```
controlpanel = display.newGroup()
controlpanel:insert(lifeBar)
```

and then in the

```
 scene:exitScene(event))

controlpanel=self.view
```

but it doesn't work :( any ideal about how to code this ?

By the way, it works with livesValue because it could be "inserted" in the groupe called screenGroup. My question is : is it possible to insert a table (in my case, called "lifeBar") in a group ?

Comment: By the way, it works with livesValue because it could be "inserted" in the groupe called screenGroup. My question is : is it possible to insert a table (in my case, called "lifeBar") in a group ?

Comment: Ok but please edit your question this is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted your code does not show that you add all the different `lifeBar` objects to the scene group so they should remain visible on every scene (read about the default stage in corona). Once add them, you may have to `removeSelf` each one at scene exit or destroy can't verify right now.

Alternately you could add them all to the display group you tried but then don't forget to add that group to `scene.view`, and to `removeSelf` the group on exit or destroy event of scene.

Comment: Thank you ! It works ! I  added all the different lifeBar objects to the scene group and now i can remove them at the end of the scene :)